# How to manage localizations for iOS and Android apps in runtime?

Tags: android, ios, localization

There is a really great tool for that:

https://www.localizationkit.com

But this is only for iOS;( I may change any translation for any language at any time and the app will get the updated translations as soon as it will be opened. But what about Android? That pretty good tool doesnt support android;(

Do you know any other to support both: **ios & android**?